# Dompdf não carrega com arquivo 80mmx30mm

Tags: php, pdf, dompdf

Estou tentando gerar um PDF para ser impresso como etiqueta tamanho **80x30**, mas ao definir esse tamanho o PDF não carrega. Dimensões maiores carregam normalmente.

```
$customPaper = array(0,0,80,30);
$dompdf->set_paper($customPaper, 'portrait');
```

A página é em PHP e demora a carregar, dá erro como se o tempo máximo de carregamento fosse atingido.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Recebe algum erro !

Comment: A página demora a carregar, e dá erro como se o tempo máximo de carregamento fosse atingido.

Comment: Coloque o código todo para avaliar, mas para testar reduza ao exemplo mais simples, apenas uma página em branco com essas dimensões e construa a partir de aí

Comment: Removi o conteúdo que iria na tabela e carregou o PDF. Percebi que não converti as dimensões para pixel e conteúdo do PDF estava maior que as dimensões do arquivo. Obrigado!